# ASP.net How to use a sql parameter for a datasource

Tags: asp.net, sql, datasource, sqlparameter

I'm trying to load some specific information on a page depending on what logged in user loads the page. I did my best googling my problem but I couldn't find the solution.

```
   <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:werknem taken connection string %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT [Description], [State], [assessment] FROM [TaskInfo] WHERE ([EmployeeID] = @EmployeeID)">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="" Name="@EmployeeID" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

And

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data
Partial Class werknemer
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("@EmployeeID", User.Identity.Name)
        GridView1.DataBind()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Some help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Oh I forgot to say that EmployeeID in my table has the same name as the login accounts. For example I got an account with login "Paul" and  I've got a "Paul" in my sqlTable under employeeID

Comment: Try `SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters("@EmployeeID") =  User.Identity.Name`

Comment: I replace This line: SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("@EmployeeID", User.Identity.Name) with your line of code but it didn't work. Am I doing something wrong? thanks for answering.

Comment: Remove the `@` from your parameter name. Should be `<asp:Parameter  Name="EmployeeID"` and `SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters("EmployeeID") = `